# Как в React Native использовать несколько компонентов DateTimePicker

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

Как оптимизировать код в React Native, для использования в одной форме, нескольких компонентов DateTimePicker?

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал это через хуки

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, Picker } from 'react-native'
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker'

function useInput() {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const showMode = (currentMode) => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
    };
    const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
    };

    const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
        const currentDate = selectedDate || date
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setDate(currentDate);
    }
    return {
        date,
        showDatepicker,
        show,
        mode,
        onChange
    }
}

export const MainScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const input = useInput(new Date())
    const input2 = useInput(new Date())
return (
        <View >
           <Button              
              onPress={input.showDatepicker}
              title={input.date.toLocaleDateString()} />
              {input.show && (
                   <DateTimePicker
                   testID="dateTimePicker1"
                   value={input.date}
                   mode={input.mode}
                   is24Hour={true}
                   display="default"
                   onChange={input.onChange}
                   />
               )}

            <Button              
              onPress={input2.showDatepicker}
              title={input2.date.toLocaleDateString()} />
              {input2.show && (
                   <DateTimePicker
                   testID="dateTimePicker2"
                   value={input2.date}
                   mode={input2.mode}
                   is24Hour={true}
                   display="default"
                   onChange={input2.onChange}
                    />
              )}
  )
}
```